# XCM Barrier blocked execution: when transferring XC-20 between 2 local Moonbase parachains

Tags: polkadot, xcm, moonbeam

The setup is:

- polkadot-launch
- 1 relay chain: polkadot-0.9.18 rococo
- 2 parachains: moonbeam-0.24.0 moonbase-local

  - paraId 1000
  - paraId 1001
- open hrmp channel via polkadot-launch

Transferring DOT between Relay chain and parachain is ok:

1. `assetManager.registerForeignAsset`
2. `assetManager.setAssetUnitsPerSecond`
3. relay chain -> parachain `xcmPallet.limitedReserveTransferAssets`
4. parachain -> relay chain `xtokens.transfer`

However, transferring parachain native token between 2 Moonbeam parachains is failed:
parachain 1001 -> parachain 1000

1. On parachain 1000:
   `assetManager.registerForeignAsset`
2. On parachain 1000: `assetManager.setAssetUnitsPerSecond`
3. On parachain 1001:
   `xTokens.transfer` This step failed.

The sender parachain 1001 successfully send the xcm message, but receiver parachain 1000 throw an error when executing this message.

Maybe the xcm multilocation is wrong.

[image]

The error log of receiver parachain 1000 is as follows:

```
2022-07-07 11:14:00.028 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker xcm::should_execute: [] 
did not pass barrier: 
origin: 
    MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(1001)) }, 
message: 
    Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(
        MultiAssets([
            MultiAsset {
                id: Concrete(
                    MultiLocation {
                        parents: 1,
                        interior: X2(Parachain(1001), PalletInstance(3))
            }),
                fun: Fungible(1000000000)
        }
    ])),
    ClearOrigin,
    BuyExecution {
        fees: MultiAsset {
            id: Concrete(MultiLocation {
                parents: 1,
                interior: X2(Parachain(1001), PalletInstance(3))
            }),
            fun: Fungible(1000000000)
        },
        weight_limit: Limited(100)
    },
    DepositAsset {
        assets: Wild(All),
        max_assets: 1,
        beneficiary: MultiLocation {
            parents: 0,
            interior: X1(AccountKey20 {
                network: Any,
                key: [
                    242,
                    79,
                    243,
                    169,
                    207,
                    4,
                    199,
                    29,
                    188,
                    148,
                    208,
                    181,
                    102,
                    247,
                    162,
                    123,
                    148,
                    86,
                    108,
                    172
                ]
            })
        }
    }
]) 
max_weight: 400000000, 
weight_credit: 0

2022-07-07 11:14:00.028 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker xcm::execute_xcm_in_credit: [] Barrier blocked execution! Error: (). (origin: MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(1001)) }, message: Xcm([ReserveAssetDeposited(MultiAssets([MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(1001), PalletInstance(3)) }), fun: Fungible(1000000000) }])), ClearOrigin, BuyExecution { fees: MultiAsset { id: Concrete(MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X2(Parachain(1001), PalletInstance(3)) }), fun: Fungible(1000000000) }, weight_limit: Limited(100) }, DepositAsset { assets: Wild(All), max_assets: 1, beneficiary: MultiLocation { parents: 0, interior: X1(AccountKey20 { network: Any, key: [242, 79, 243, 169, 207, 4, 199, 29, 188, 148, 208, 181, 102, 247, 162, 123, 148, 86, 108, 172] }) } }]), weight_limit: 41666666666, weight_credit: 0)    
2022-07-07 11:14:00.028 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker cumulus_pallet_xcmp_queue: [] Failed to process XCMP-XCM message, caused by Barrier
```

Update: I make it after adding a xcm barrier to Moonbase.

https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/PureStake/moonbeam@8369da6dd073e1dc757deda2a778648c15c8298e/-/blob/runtime/moonbase/src/xcm_config.rs?L223

```rust
// Allow paid executions
pub type XcmBarrier = (
    TakeWeightCredit,
    AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>,
    AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<Everything>, // add this line, allow every xcm message
    AllowKnownQueryResponses<PolkadotXcm>,
    // Subscriptions for version tracking are OK.
    AllowSubscriptionsFrom<Everything>,
);
```

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, but I cannot modify the xcm configuration of the destination chain (in your case Moonbase). Is there any other way of solving without adding any configuration?